# How to prevent the camera from seeing through walls in Bevy?

Tags: bevy

Using Bevy, I made a 3d maze, but when I try to navigate the maze, the camera can see through the walls.  Looking down a corridor, the wall ahead will appear but as it gets closer, it just cuts off and I can see through to the other corridor.

I am using `Box` sprites for the walls as so:

```
commands
    .spawn(PbrBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(Mesh::from(shape::Box::new(1.0, 1.0, 0.1))),
        material: materials.add(Color::rgb(0.8, 0.7, 0.6).into()),
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(x, 0.5, y+0.5)),
        ..Default::default()
    });
```

and my camera is added as so:

```
commands
    .spawn(Camera3dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(-2.0, 0.5, 0.0))
            .looking_at(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0), Vec3::unit_y()),
        ..Default::default()
    })
```

Is there anything extra I need to do to the perspective to prevent it from seeing through objects that are too close to it?  Ideally it would never see through objects.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that my walls were spaced exactly 1 unit apart, and the default nearfield perspective is 1.0.  Decreasing the `near` parameter of the perspective on the camera to 0.01 prevented seeing through the walls when too close to them.

in main.rs:

```
use bevy_render::camera::PerspectiveProjection;

commands
    .spawn(Camera3dBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(-2.0, 0.5, 0.0))
            .looking_at(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.5, 0.0), Vec3::unit_y()),
        perspective_projection: PerspectiveProjection {
            near: 0.01,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        ..Default::default()
    })
```

in cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
bevy_render = "0.4"
```